# How to fix passing in data from api to display correctly in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to gather the data I collect from the API crypto compare and display into a table. I am able to generate the  and  append them to the table body. I keep running into this weird problem where every time I iterate with a for loop each individual data for the coin doesn't go into each row but instead places all the data, all 100 into 1 row.

When I assign I to any number the table has no problem showing 1 coin, which then takes up 1 row like it's supposed too.

I have tried assigning the class names to variables where I would append the data to the variable of the classes that didn't work.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < $marketCapNumber; i++) {
  $('.a').append(
    "<tr class='tableRowData'>" +
      "<td class='rank data' id = '1'> </td>" +
      "<td class='name data' id = '2'> </td>" +
      "<td class=' symbol data' id= '3'> </td>" +
      "<td class=' marketCap data' id ='4'> </td>" +
      "<td class='price data' id='5'> </td>" +
      "</tr>"
  );
}



//data from the API 
for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
  // Name

  let name = data.Data[j].CoinInfo.FullName;
  // symbol e.g btc, xrp, ltc
  let symbol = data.Data[j].DISPLAY.USD.FROMSYMBOL;
  //  price
  let price = data.Data[j].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE;
  //   marketcap
  let $marcketCap = data.Data[j].DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP;


  //   created inputs
  const $nameOfCoin = $('<p>').text(`${name}`);
  const $ticker = $('<p>').text(`${symbol}`);
  const $coinprice = $('<p>').text(`${price}`);
  const $totalMarketCap = $('<p>').text(`${$marcketCap}`);
  // assigning variable to class names
    const nameClass = $('.name');
    const symbolClass= $('.symbol');
    const priceClass = $('.price');
    const marketCapClass = $('.marketCap');
  // append to the <td>
  $(nameClass).append($nameOfCoin);
  $(symbolClass).append($ticker);
  $(priceClass).append($coinprice);
  $(marketCapClass).append($totalMarketCap);

}
```

I am expecting to iterate through each coin and add that coins info to one row of data, instead its adding the entire list of coins to 1 row for each row. Whenever I take away the for loop and just assign it a number it will place the coins info in the row individually. How can I fix this since I'm trying to pass in each coin that corresponds with the array and not just showcase one number 100 times?

Comment: Explain this "1 row for each row."   Is are you saying for all Rows in the Table the value in a "Column" is the same?  100 down the column?

Comment: My bad, I mean its printing out the 100 coins but it's placing all 100 coins in 1 row for 100 rows! All I want is for 1 coin per row for the 100 coins.

Comment: What's this guys value `$marketCapNumber`?h

Answer (score 0):

Once the table is created and you do this `$(priceClass).append($coinprice);` that's grabbing every single instance of `<td class='price data' id = '5'> </td>` in the table and appending the value of $coinprice to every single one of them.  In the end if I had an array of 5 coins 1 - 5 I'd expect to see this `<td class='price data' id='5'><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p></td>` for every row of the table.